# Evaluar una condición/función en formato string

Tags: python, string, substring, evaluación

Hola tengo un cadena de texto que necesito evaluar si su condición se cumple y no logro ver la forma de hacerlo... ejemplo del caso:

```
LNCEL_FDD = {'dlMimoMode':'43', 'actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch':'true'}

condicion = 'LNCEL_FDD.dlMimoMode == 43 and LNCEL_FDD.actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch != true'

intente con  res = eval(condicion ) ## no funciona
```

otra forma seria convertir los substring, en formato para acceder al dic y así se podría utilizar eval() ??:

```
condicion = 'LNCEL_FDD[dlMimoMode] == 43 and LNCEL_FDD[actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch] != true'
```

pero NO se como hacerlo! me podrán ayudar con este caso? desde ya gracias por su tiempo... saludos

Comment: Si entiendo bien, recibes la condición en forma de string, pero no funciona por que no es la forma correcta de acceder al diccionario. Mi pregunta sería, tienes control sobre la creación de esas cadenas o ya te vienen así de algún otro lado?

Comment: @DanteS.  esas condiciones ya me viene así en ese formato, no tengo control sombre ellas... gracias

Comment: Otra pregunta. La condición que recibes y no funciona siempre va a estar código Python? O siempre sigue la constante de que es una comparación de Python en la cual intentas acceder a las claves del diccionario con atributos?

Comment: Parece que el true está en minusculas, lo cual no le caería bien a Python. Supongo que debería ser 'true'.

Comment: Creo que la respuesta a tu pregunta depende de que tan parecido a Python es el lenguaje de programación en el que está la cadena. Podrías agregar más información sobre esa cadena a la pregunta por favor?

Comment: @DanteS.  los datos los recibo en formato dataframe donde tiene una columna "parametro" donde veo  el parametro a verificar  y una columna "condicion"  que es la que debe cumplir. Tengo otro df con los valores encontrados de esos parámetros que  recorro por fila con  df_encontrados.apply(funcion, axis = 1) y miro si el parámetro con su valor encontrado cumple o no con la condicion del otro df (donde están el nombre del parámetro y su condición), es complicado, por eso solo quería saber como traducir ese string y ver de ocuparlo para resolver el tema... gracias

Comment: Te daré una respuesta, pero sin saber las diferencias que hay entre sintaxis Python y la condición, es muy probable que no te sirva.

Comment: @DanteS. los datos los traigo de una API, las condiciones NO están hechas para interprete python es para otra plataforma por eso true esta en minúsculas, en si estos datos l true/false/<>/=  los convierto luego  con replace() PERO lo que no pude es lo que comente, LNCEl_FDD.parametro llevarlo a formato que entienda python

Comment: Creo que si dieras información sobre que plataforma es, te podríamos ayudar mejor. Ya que parece que podrías necesitar un convertidor de dicho lenguaje a Python. Por cierto, ten cuidado con replace, te podría dar conflictos en condiciones como 'hola_mundo="<>"'. El tema es que el true sin comillas no puede ser bien interpretado por Python. Lo tomaría como un nombre de variable. El numerito en la condición antes del and se interpretaría como numero, no como cadena. De casualidad es sql?

Answer (score 0):

Primero: para acceder a los valores de un diccionario se usan los `[]`. La forma que usas (con ".") se usa para acceder a los atributos de un objeto, que no es lo que buscas.

Segundo: debes poner la llave del diccionario como string (entre cremillas). Si omites las cremillas, entonces Python buscara una variable con ese nombre. Como esa variable no existe, se produce un error.

Tercero: en este caso los valores del diccionario son strings; en la condición debes colocarlos encerrados entre cremillas.

Cuarto: `exec()` no retorna nada. Si quieres capturar el resultado de un condición, debes asignarlo a una variable, y acceder a ella luego de ejecutar el `exec()`

```
LNCEL_FDD = {'dlMimoMode':'43', 'actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch':'true'}

condicion = 'resultado = LNCEL_FDD["dlMimoMode"] == "43" and LNCEL_FDD["actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch"] != "true"'
exec(condicion)
print(resultado)
```

produce:

```
False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Alternativa con f-string

En lugar de usar `exec()` puedes simplemente encerrar la expresión completa entre `{}` y anteponerle una "f", con lo que lograras la evaluación de la condición:

```
LNCEL_FDD = {'dlMimoMode':'43', 'actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch':'not true'}

condicion = f'{LNCEL_FDD["dlMimoMode"] == "43" and LNCEL_FDD["actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch"] != "true"}'
print(condicion)
```

produce:

```
True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Eval me parece más seguro, pues es un poquito más dificil ejecutar código arbitrario.

Comment: Los f-strings devuelven una cadena. Lo mejor es eval, que devolverá autenticamente el resultado de la compraración. De cualquier modo lamentablemente el OP no tiene control sobre la cadena que le llega como para aplicar tu respuesta (lee los comentarios de la pregunta).

Comment: @Candid Moe gracias por tu respuesta, el tema en si es como transformar ese estring  para utilizar exec porque ya me viene en el formato descripto... por lo que comentas, estaría mas orientado a utilizar una class para tratar dichas condiciones como LNCEL_FDD.atributo..

Comment: @DanteS. averigüe para que plataforma esta hecho la forma de string condicional y me dicen que para python 2, pero como dice Candid Moe esta hecho además  apuntando a un atributo de una clase...

Comment: Si es Python 2 entonces será mucho más fácil el uso del modulo ast, ya que la sintaxis de Python 2 y 3 son parecidas (aunque no iguales). Por cierto, te sirve mi respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solución

Si logras por otros medios que tu condición tenga una sintaxis Python valida, puedes usar el modulo [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/ast.html) para procesarla como si fuera código Python y modificarla.

```
import ast

# Esta clase se encarga de visitar cada nodo y permite modificar el nodo visitado.
class Transformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    # Visito todos los nodos que consisten en acceder a atributos de clase.
    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        # Verifico que el objeto al que se quiere acceder esté en una variable y que esa variable sea "LNCEL_FDD"
        if(isinstance(node.value, ast.Name) and node.value.id == "LNCEL_FDD"):
            # Esto es equivalente a convertir esto a.b a a["b"]
            node = ast.Subscript(value=node.value,
                                 slice=ast.Index(value=ast.Constant(node.attr)),
                                 ctx=node.ctx)            
        return node

transformer = Transformer()

def to_pycond(string):
    # parseamos la condición
    code = ast.parse(string, mode="eval")

    # modificamos la condición
    new_code = transformer.visit(code)

    ast.fix_missing_locations(new_code)

    # compilamos la condición para que se pueda ejecutar en eval.
    return compile(new_code, 'condición', 'eval')

LNCEL_FDD = {'dlMimoMode':'43', 'actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch':'true'}

print(eval(to_pycond('LNCEL_FDD.dlMimoMode == 43 and LNCEL_FDD.actCsiRsSubFNonTM9Sch != true')))
```

#### Aviso 1

Esto produce `False`, lo cual es correcto pero por casualidad. Ya que la parte que devuelve False y hace que el resto devuelva False es esta: `LNCEL_FDD.dlMimoMode == 43`. El transformador que escribí no convierte constantes en cadenas. Entonces intenta saber si un numero y una cadena son iguales, lo cual siempre es falso.

Incluso si esta parte diera True, ocurriría luego un error al evaluar a la segunda condición, ya que Python creería que `true` es una variable. Como esa variable no existe, produciría un error.

Supongo que esas cosas las irás trabajando con el tiempo y las pruebas.

#### Aviso 2

El uso de eval puede ser peligroso, ya que permite ejecutar código arbitrario de Python. En lo posible evita su uso. Y si lo necesitas y el usuario tiene posibilidad de escribir un comando, mejor será usar blacklists o whitelists con ayuda del modulo ast.

---

Yo en lo personal te recomendaría que recurras a algún parser de la plataforma para la cual la condición fue diseñada y con ayuda de eso crear código Python. Sin embargo, este tipo de solución la he aplicado en un lenguaje de programación discontinuado llamado clipper y es un buen tapabaches (aunque no es lo mejor).